# Javascript: Trouble parsing json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, spring

Spring is returning a json-encoded object with four properties.  One of which is a property named "array".  I want the contents of this array.

Here's the whole json response:

```
ee
{"map":null,"array":[{"id":2,"description":"Cloud For Dev","businessSize":2,"businessType":9,"businessLocation":3},{"id":3,"description":"Cloud For Prod","businessSize":2,"businessType":9,"businessLocation":3}],"string":null,"bool":false}
0
```

I'm not actually sure what the "ee" or 0 mean...  Anyway, I'm trying to parse it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/ajax/rest/teamService/list",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        var teamArray = response.array;

        var $el = $("#teamSelect");
        $el.empty(); 

        $.each(teamArray[0], function(team) {
                alert(team.description);
                $el.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", team.id).text(team.description));
        });

        // Reattach the plugin
        $("#teamSelect").selectbox("detach");
        $("#teamSelect").selectbox("attach");
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (textStatus === 'error') {
            setTimeout(function() { window.location = '/do/login'; }, 7000);
        }
    }
});
```

And I'm getting the alert box pop up 6 times (should be 2), and each time it says "undefined" rather than the actual description.

The select box itself has four empty options.

Seems like I'm iterating over the json encoded object's four parameters, NOT the two contents of the enclosed array.

How can I fix this?

Comment: That's simply not a valid JSON string. Those "ee" and 0 screw the syntax and the response cannot be parsed.

Comment: I'm suspicious of those two bits as well.  I see them in fiddler's display of the json response, and I'm not sure what they mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -   `teamArray[0]` should be only `teamArray`

```
$.each(teamArray, function(i,team) {
    alert(team.description);
    $el.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", team.id).text(team.description));
});
```

Comment: This causes it to popup undefined twice, which is the correct number of times.  team.description and team.id are null.  So closer, but not yet correct.

Comment: That returns the correct data.  Problem solved, but why 'this' rather than 'team'?

Comment: `$.each(teamArray, function(i,team){ team.description}`  you had only one parameter that is why it wasn't working... see the updated code to use it with `team`

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you're looping over the keys of `teamArray[0]`, hence the six alerts. Loop over `teamArray`. Also, `$.each`'s callback [takes `indexInArray, valueOfElement`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). May as well not jQuery through that:

```
for(var i = 0; i < teamArray.length; i++) {
    var team = teamArray[i];
    ...
}
```